# probabilty, random variable independent

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Poisson random random variables with ($\lambda=1$). Are $X-Y$ and $X+Y$ independent? Justify

My attempt:

$X-Y$ => random variable is $0$.

$X+Y$=> Poisson of ($\lambda=2$).

yes? they are independent?

Comment: It is not the case that $X-Y$ is the zero variable...

Comment: @Potato, can you please explain why X-Y is not?

Comment: They're independent. They don't have to take the same values. So $X$ could $1$ and $Y$ could be $2$, for example, and you would have $X-Y\neq 0$.

Comment: @Potato, yes, you are right, let me change it then

Comment: As a side note, $X-Y$ has Skellam distribution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unconditional probability that $X-Y=0$ is not $1$. The conditional probability that $X-Y=0$, given that $X+Y=0$, is obviously $1$. So our random variables are not independent.

Alternately, and almost equivalently, we have $\Pr((X+Y=0)\land (X-Y=0))=\Pr(X=0)\Pr(Y=0)=e^{-2}$.

But $\Pr(X+Y=0)=e^{-2}$ and $\Pr(X-Y=0)\lt 1$, and therefore 
$$\Pr((X+Y=0)\land (X-Y=0))\ne \Pr(X+Y=0)\Pr(X-Y=0).$$
Hence $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are not independent.